# Setting an option that can only be viewed by users in a certain group

Tags: python, django, authentication, view, usergroups

I am quite new to django and am building a project using django and python predominantly.

I have two user groups in djangos admin panel created and defined there with user added through this admin panel;
Diving_Officers and Club_Members

In my webpage, i have an option that i want to only be visible or even clickable to the users in one group, the Diving_Officers group.
I cannot find any specific information for how to call a group that exists in django admin and assign it permissions or how to limit a view to it.

**in short how do i add a set of permissions to a group, ie. people in this group can only view this page

Answer (score 0):

On a view you can use the decorator @user_passes_test() (you can find more informations here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default)

to make the option visible only to user in that group instead you can use a template filter, create a "templatetags" folder in your app and add this into "has_group.py" in that folder:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def has_group(user, group_name):
     return user.groups.filter(name=group_name).exists()
```

then, after loading in the template with "load has_group" you can use user|has_group:"mygroup" as if condition